# How to install python packages in a Google Dataproc cluster

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

Is it possible to install python packages in a Google Dataproc cluster after the cluster is created and running?

I tried to use "`pip install xxxxxxx`" in the master command line but it does not seem to work.

Google's Dataproc documentation does not mention this situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is generally not possible after cluster is created. I recommend using an initialization action to do this.

As you've noticed, `pip` is also not available by default. So you'll want to run `easy_install pip` followed by `pip install` command.

Finally, if your intention is to use this cluster in any automation, and/or you want hermeticness, I recommend creating a `wheel` that you store in GCS and download in init action. You'd then install your wheel. Wheels have added benefit of being faster than installing many packages from pip directly.

**2019 Update**

See this tutorial on how to configure Python environment on Dataproc:
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration

Comment: Thanks a lot, when using the Jupyter Notebook I was able to install the packages using !pip install package in the notebook.

Comment: Great article on setting up production pyspark jobs if that's what your after, including bundling modules using a Makefile and deploying when running jobs: https://developerzen.com/best-practices-writing-production-grade-pyspark-jobs-cb688ac4d20f