# Is there a way to pip install a wheel or tar.gz python package in google dataproc initialization-actions

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to `pip install package psycopg2` on the Dataproc cluster. I have tried the following but as my work computer has firewall restrictions so this isn't working.

```sh
REGION=<region>
gcloud dataproc clusters create my-cluster \
  --image-version 1.4 \
  --metadata 'CONDA_PACKAGES=psycopg2' \
  --metadata 'PIP_PACKAGES=psycopg2' \
  --initialization-actions \
  gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/python/conda-install.sh,gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-${REGION}/python/pip-install.sh
```

So now i have placed the `psycopg2.whl` and also `psycopg2.tar.gz` files ins GSC. Now I need to install them somehow during Dataproc cluster creation and seems its possible after looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50280108/13433956 
Can anyone provide more details on how to get pip to install the `whl` or `tar.gz` file to install from GCS through Dataproc initialization-actions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to do this you can customize your initialization action to

1. Download the wheel package from gcs to local file system
2. pip install [local wheel package] from there.
3. Create cluster using your customized initialization action file under a GCS path.

Please follow the [best practice](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/blob/master/README.md#how-initialization-actions-are-used) when doing so.

Comment: Ok so you mean that create a script say that'd do something like                                                                
    pip install gs://<gcs_location>/psycopg2.tar.gz and then in init action i'll call it by                                 
    gcloud dataproc clusters create my-cluster \ --image-version 1.4 \ --initialization-actions \ gs://<gcs_location>\install.sh

Comment: Right, but you might have to download the gs://<gcs_location>/psycopg2.tar.gz to some vm local path to install the wheel package. I haven't seen pip supports a gs:// path for install.